# Cannot find library reference to libmysqlclient_r Angstrom

Tags: c++, mysql, linker, linker-errors, connector

I downloaded the MySQL Connector / C++ code from dev.mysql.com. I also used opkg to download the libmysqlclient-r-dev package, which gave me libmysqlclient_r.so and .la in my /usr/lib directory.

When I attempt to make the source code for the MySQL connector, I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient_r
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [driver/libmysqlcppconn.so.1.0.5] Error 1
make[1]: *** [driver/CMakeFiles/mysqlcppconn.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It tells me that the library is missing, eventhough it is present in /usr/lib?
How does that work, and what should I do?